# Faster SQL data retrival with Java and search large data

Tags: java, sql, hashmap

I have a table with over 100 thousand data consisting of number pairs. A sample of which is shown below.

```
   A          B
   0010     0010 
    0010     0011 
    0010     0019 
    0010     0056
    0011     0010 
    0011     0011 
    0011     0019 
    0011     0040
    0019     0010
    0019     0058
```

Here the numbers in Column A has possible pairs present in column B. 
Explanation : User will have several of these numbers ranging form 10 -100. Now as we can see for 0010 - 0011 and 0019 is present. So if the user has a list containing 0010 along with 0011 a warning will be shown that this pair is not allowed and vice versa.

How to approach this in Java?
Loading the hash map with all the data doesnot seem to be a good option although the search will be much faster.

please suggest. Thanks

Testcase:

```
num = 0010;  //value from list which user will be passing
test(num){
if(num.equals("0019")||num.equals("0011")) //compairing with database 
System.out.println("incompatible pair present");
}
```

The above example is a very simple pseudo code. The actual problem will me much more complex.

Comment: This problem is interesting, but could you clarify it a little more please?  I'm having difficulty trying to understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: How about of some test cases of what this should do?

Comment: How bout the test case added . does that clarify a little.

Comment: Your pseudo-code prints out "incompatible ..." whenever user input is equal to "0019" or "0011". Is that really what you want to address? And where we see these "pairs" in the testcase? I really do not understand your question exactly.

Comment: Seems like the problem is still not clear. What are your inputs and outputs?

Comment: The problem is simple, I am not sure wat is still unclear.

Comment: Sql has column A and B. A contains some values. Lets say A contains numbers 1-100. Now with 1, values like 17, 59 are incompatible(for example) and vice versa. So when the user has a list of values like 1, 14, 67.. the code will check that it should not contain 17 or 57(this is only for 1.Similarly for 14 and 67 we need to check. If contains error message will be shown.

Comment: Ok, did another answer for that. All right now? Please edit your question then to clarify things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252689/faster-sql-data-retrival-with-java-and-search-large-data/6275810#6275810

Answer (score 2):

Until the question is more clear...
Handling large amounts of data which are already stored in a database let me give you a recommendation: Whatever you want to do here, consider solving it with SQL instead of Java. Or at least write a SQL with an resulting ResultSet which is easy to evaluate in Java afterwards.

But until the question is not that clear ...

Comment: for 10 such combinations if evertime i need to hit the database the response time will be much more. So I am thinking of solving it in java itself after getting all the values.

Comment: That's the problem: It is not clear what your question is about. And I do NOT think you have to hit the databse for any combination again, but ...

Comment: please see my explanation in the last comment.

Comment: I've created a separate answer. Maybe I finally understood what you want?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252689/faster-sql-data-retrival-with-java-and-search-large-data/6275810#6275810

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find entries where A is the same value but B is different?

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.b 
FROM MyTable t1, MyTable t2 
WHERE t1.a = t2.b AND t1.b <> t2.b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried of running out of heap space, you could try using a persistent cache like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/). I suggest you check the actual memory consumed before going in for this solution though

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem is limited to a very small domain - why cant you instantiate an two dimensional array of `bool` and set it to `true` whenever the indexes of two numbers creates an unsupported combination.

Example for usage:

```
if (forbiden[10][11] || forbiden[11][10]) 
{
   throw new Exception("pairs of '10' and '11' are not allowed");
}
```

You can instantiate this array from the database by going over the data once and setting this array. You just need to translate `0010` to `10`. You will have junk in Indexes 0-9, but you can eliminate it by "translating" the index by subtracting it from `9`.

Does that hit your question?

Comment: Please see my clarification in the last added comment

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly what you want to do…

Create a unique index on `t1(a,b)`. Put the user's new pair in an INSERT statement *inside a try block*. Catch key violation exceptions (will be a`SQLException`, possibly a subclass depending on your RDBMS) and explain to the user that is a forbidden pair.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the question:
You have a table containing two numbers each record which are declared 'incompatible'.
You have a user list of numbers and you want to check if this list contains 'incompatible numbers'. Right?

Here you go with a simple SQL (took your example from comment):

```
SELECT *
FROM   incompatible
WHERE  A IN (1, 14, 67) AND B IN (1, 14, 67);
```

This SQL returns all incompatibilities. When the resultset is empty then there are no incompatibilities and everything is fine. If you only want to retrieve this fact then you can write `SELECT 1 ...` instead.
The SQL have to be build dynamically to contain the user's numbers in the `IN` clauses, of course.

To speed up queries you can create an (unique) index over both columns. So the database can do a index range scan (unique).
If this table does not yet contain a primary key then you should create a primary key over both columns.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - definitely not scalable solution -- if your ranges really are 0000 - 9999.

Simply have a byte table with 999999 entries.
Each entry consists of a simple 0 for allowed or 1 for not allowed.
You find an entry in the table by logically concatenating the two pair numbers (key =  first * 1000 + second).

The more scalable database solution is to create a table with a composite primary key (pair1 and pair2) the mere presence of an entry indicating a disallowed pair.